# Возможно ли при наследовании методы объединять, а не заменять?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, наследование

Например есть родительский класс и дочерний, который наследуется от него

```
class Parent():
    def test(self):
        print('inside parent')

class Child(Parent):
    def test(self):
        print('inside child')
```

при вызове метода экземпляра дочернего класса с тем же названием вызывается функция из дочернего класса, перезаписывая родительскую

```
>>> b1 = Child()
>>> b1.test()
inside child
>>>
```

Вопрос: можно ли сделать так чтобы дочерний метод `не перезаписывал` родительский, а `добавлялся` к нему и они выполнялись бы вместе и поочередно (сначала родительский потом дочерний)? Чтобы получилось вот так:

```
>>> b1.test()
inside parent
inside child
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для этого можно вызвать функцию в родительском классе при помощи `super()`.

```
class Parent:
    def test(self):
        print('inside parent')


class Child(Parent):
    def test(self):
        super().test()
        print('inside child')


b1 = Child()
b1.test()
```

Вывод:

```
inside parent
inside child
```

Подробнее про функцию `super()` можете почитать в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).